# How to pass json in request header Using rest and method= POST

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

I want to pass json as **request header** in rest api request call using POST method.

Json :- `{
    "comment" : "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "visibility" : {
        "code" : "anyone"
    }
}`

```
     PageReference p = new PageReference(LINKEDIN_SHAREPOST+LINKEDIN_ACCESSTOKEN+'&format=json');
     p.getParameters().put('{"comment":"Check out developer.linkedin.com!","visibility":{"code": "anyone"}}'); 
     String body = p.getURL();
     body = body.subStringAfter('?');
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint(LINKEDIN_SHAREPOST);
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setCompressed(false);
     req.setHeader('HOST','www.linkedin.com');
```

Its giving me error. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this by Creating classes as below :

```
public class linkedinpostshare_API 
{
public String comment='';
public Content content{get;set;}
public Visibility visibility{get;set;}
public class Content 
{
    public String title='';
    public String description='';
    public String submitted_url='';
    public String submitted_image_url='';        
}
public class Visibility 
{
    public String code='';
} 

}
```

assign the class properties and make Rest API POST Call As below.

```
 linkedinpostshare_API objlinkedinpostshare_API = new linkedinpostshare_API();         
     linkedinpostshare_API.Visibility objVisibility = new linkedinpostshare_API.Visibility();

     objVisibility.code='anyone';
     objlinkedinpostshare_API.comment=post;         
     objlinkedinpostshare_API.visibility=objVisibility;       

     String jsonBody = json.serialize(objlinkedinpostshare_API);        
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setEndpoint(LINKEDIN_SHAREPOST+token+'&format=json');
     req.setMethod('POST');
     req.setCompressed(false);
     req.setHeader('HOST','www.linkedin.com');
     req.setHeader('Encoding','iso-8859-1'); 
     req.setHeader('Content-Type', LINKEDIN_REQUEST_CONTENTTYPE);
     req.setHeader('x-li-format', 'json');         
     req.setTimeout(120000);//max timeout
      if(jsonBody != null )
         { 
             req.setBody(jsonBody);
             req.setHeader('Content-length',string.valueOf(jsonBody.length()));
         }
         HttpResponse res = new http().send(req);

       return res.getBody();
```